# How can I convert this program from using for loop to indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, runge-kutta

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""CP Q4.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lIuthEQwk1StdYV32yUJhRjPP8PHCYEV
"""

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
##import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
# %matplotlib inline

#defining RK4 method
def RK4(t, f, y0):
    y = np.zeros((len(t), len(y0))); y[0] = y0
    h = t[1] - t[0]
    for i in range(0, len(t)-1):
        k1 = h * f(t[i], y[i])
        k2 = h * f(t[i]+h/2, y[i]+k1/2)
        k3 = h * f(t[i]+h/2, y[i]+k2/2)
        k4 = h * f(t[i]+h, y[i]+k3)    
        y[i+1] = y[i] + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) / 6
        
    return y

#defining SIR sytem of functions
def func(t, y):
    b, g = 0.143, 0.071
    S = -1*b*y[0]*y[1]
    I = b*y[0]*y[1]-g*y[1]
    R = g*y[1]
    sol = np.array([S, I, R])
    return sol

print(RK4(t,func,y0))
```

I want to use indexing method instead of the for loop applied inside the RK4 function to achieve similar results. Is it possible to replace the for loop with some indexing method?

Comment: I don't think it can be done, because the algorithm calculates the solution step by step iteratively.

Comment: Could you explain what your rationale for this change is? For reducing the effort of the integration, the first step is to change from step-size oriented to error-oriented methods, that is, adaptive step-size control. Then there are the diverse compilation options numba.jit, JITCode, cython,... If the equation is just a mockup for some larger task, using adapted linear-algebra for the larger state space could also speed up the computation. But that then leads away from python,...

Comment: This was actually a part of my class assignment but I misunderstood question so I will be taking down this question. Thanks for all your inputs!